# making a mouse over event for a div efficiently

Tags: javascript, asp.net, mouseover

have made a simple mouse over event for "maindiv" using javascript,
 -  to visible "divsub"

and a mouse out event
  - to hide "divsub"

works fine too fine,

### problem

have to allow user to use control within "divsub" but "divsub" dissappears as soon as mouse is out of "maindiv"

### note

while asking this a few simple solutions did come to mind, now this appears like a stupid thing, but

### am interested in knowing the proper way to achieve the above "mouseover effect on a menu (made of labels)"

Comment: First, please provide sample code, at the very least pasted here, preferably in something like a jsFiddle, so we can see what you have tried and are having problems with (or at the very least reference a similar SO question and point out the differences between your question and the referenced one). Also, and I know english isn't everyone's first language, please try to be clearer.

Comment: I find this question hard to read, you should re-think your formatting style. Just a thought.

Comment: might be useful if you posted what your HTML for the menu looks like and the relevant parts of your css / javascript.

Comment: is 'divsub' inside 'maindiv?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best done in css. it will perform more efficiently too.

```
#divsub {
    display: none;
}

#maindiv:hover #divsub {
    display: block;
}
```